# Can an AngularJS based SPA use EmberJS router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js

I have evaluated a number of JS frameworks to finally zero down on AngularJS for my use case. However, EmberJS router seems very promising.

Is it possible to use EmberJS router in an AngularJS (1.3) SPA? At some point of time in future, I may also like to switch over to use Angular 2.0's router (or the potentially back-ported version to 1.x).

Any code samples/documentation, etc. to help with that will be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: Use AngularUI router, it's very powerful.

Comment: No but you could try tilde's https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/

Comment: +1 on @MilkyWayJoe's comment, because: "The Ember Router adds a DSL for declaring your app's routes on top of router.js. It defines the API for the Ember.Route class that handles intelligent defaults, rendering templates, and loading data into controllers."